# Neo4j cypher: set cutofftime (datetime) property of a node

Tags: datetime, neo4j, cypher

Need to set the datetime property of a node. Need to create a node Work:

```
CREATE (w:Work {type: "tech", mode: "E", cut_off_time: "12:10:00"})
```

There is a way in which I can define the hours, minutes and year as different properties:

`{hours: 12, minutes: 10, seconds: 00}`,

but how can I set it as a single property. How can I define it as a datetime object in neo4j, or is it just considered as a string.

Comment: have you considered storing it as seconds or milliseconds for easy epoch time comparisons?

Comment: epoch time is the time reference, but need to set time (cut off time) in 24 hours format, like 12 O'Clock

Comment: right... but 12 h, 10 m is just 43800 s or 43800000 ms... if you are looking at storing offsets as a single attribute seems like a reasonable choice to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j doesn't have a `datetime` data type. 
So you can store it :

- as a string, like you do
- in multiple fields (like you suggested)
- with a time-tree like, ie as nodes (https://neo4j.com/blog/modeling-a-multilevel-index-in-neoj4/)
- as a long into a property (ex: time in minutes)

Choice is yours, but it depends of what kind of queries you would like to do.

Cheers